# How can I displace and rearrange array element at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a function that accepts a positive integer n, e.g 5
should produce an array // [1,2,3,4,5] then each element should displace the next while the last element has nothing to display so it becomes the first element until 1 element is remaining

[1,2,3,4,5] => [1,3,5] => [5,1,3] => [5,3] => [3,5] = > [3]

I approached it like this but I couldn't figure out the source of error.

```js
function displaceMent(n){
  let arr = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) arr.push(i);
    let j = 0;
    while(arr.length > 1){
      arr =  arr[j + 1] === arr.slice(-1) ?  arr.splice(-1).concat(arr) : arr.splice(j + 1, 1);
      j++;
    }
return arr;
}

console.log(displaceMent(5))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beating Game</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the two solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```js
function displacement(n) { 

  var arr = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) arr.push(i);
  var i, j = 0;
  var times;

  while (arr.length != 1) {
    document.body.innerHTML += arr +"<br>";
  
    times =  Math.floor(arr.length/2);
  
    for (i = 0; i < times; i++)
        arr.splice(i + 1, 1);

    document.body.innerHTML += arr +"<br>";
    arr.unshift(arr.pop());
  }
}

displacement(5);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, coming to your original question. A soon as you run `arr =  arr[j + 1] === arr.slice(-1) ?  arr.splice(-1).concat(arr) : arr.splice(j + 1, 1);`, what happens is as followed.

1. Since `arr[j + 1] === arr.slice(-1)` is false, `j + 1`th element is removed from `arr` by `splice`.
2. The value returned by `splice()` is the value removed by it from `arr`. In this case it is 2.
3. `arr` gets assigned `2`.
4. `arr.length > 1` condition becomes false.
5. The loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is slightly different as it doesn't swap the last with the first if it has been displaced, which will give a different answer than above if `n` is set to, say, 7.

```js
const displace = (n) => {
  let a = Array.from(Array(n)).map((_, i) => i + 1);
  while (a.length > 1) {
    console.log(a);
    a = a.reduce((p, c, i, a) => {
      i % 2 === 0 && p.push(c);
      a.length % 2 !== 0 && p.unshift(p.pop());
      return p;
    }, []);
  }
  return a;
};

console.log(displace(5));
```